# Sample size calculation for margin of error and non-normality

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, standard-deviation

I have a function which chooses when to make a trade. I've set it loose on a bunch of market historical data, and it's generated n trades. I have the profit/loss figures for each trade, and therefore a mean profit/loss across all of my function's trades. How can I calculate how many trades I would need to make before I can be Z confident that my function is showing a win/loss rate within M of it's "true" win rate? That's to say the win rate it would exhibit on an infinite timescale. How does normal distribution play in to this?

Comment: I now no longer understand "my own" question, thanks to whoever edit this.  There's a reason we ask questions rather than just looking up the answers.

Comment: You can roll back edits you believe are not helpful. However, note that your question is collecting votes to close as "unclear what you are asking", so I'd recommend that you try to clarify what you are looking for.